# Pyrus installation failure - can't change journal to absolute path

Tags: php, pear, installation-path

I'm installing pear/DB, but this is happening for other installations of pear libraries as well.

> Pyrus\Installer\Exception: Installation failed 
>   Pyrus\AtomicFileTransaction\MultiException: ERROR: commit failed
>   Pyrus\IOException: CRITICAL - unable to complete transaction, rename
>   of journal to actual path failed
>   Pyrus\AtomicFileTransaction\RuntimeException: Cannot rollback - not in
>   a transaction

is the error.

I'm using a MAMP installation of PHP, and my PHP version is 5.3.6.

So far I've tried:

- turning off the server
- running it in sudo
- googling insanely
- stalking the chat board in stackoverflow and seeing someone else had the error, but his fix and mine don't like up (I don't have the script that is mentioned in that thread)

So... if anyone can give me a background on *why* the problem and also some ideas on what to try - that'd be great.

Comment: you could try to `strace` the pyrus call and see at which file it hangs. And use the `-v` parameter many times (`-vvvvvvvv`) to see what's going on inside.